# WinSCP Cannot overwrite. Permission issues

Tags: permissions, winscp

On my remote server A, I have a bunch of .py files.
I drag those files to a Windows machine, B, via WinSCP.
I work on these files on the Windows machine and want to import them back to server A via WinSCP.

When I try that, it says "cannot overwrite".

Obviously it's a permissions issue. I am not sure how much permission I need to give in order to have the overwrite access.

Currently, I have -r--r--r-- on these files for reading.
I am guessing I need write access? Or do I need execute access as well?

Will `chmod 755 *` be sufficient? I want to be careful with permissions so I am asking on here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That depends on what users are owner of the files and the one you connect with SCP.

If they are the same, then '-rw-r--r--' should be enough.

If they are on the same group then `-rw-rw-r--`